# htaccess URL rewrite not working for all cases

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite this url www.example.com/index.php?page=search&q=string1&type=string2 to this www.example.com/search/?q=string1&type=string2
or www.example.com/search?q=string1&type=string2.

I used the code but not works :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^search?([^/]*)$ index.php?page=search&$1 [L,NC]
```

can anybody give the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/myprojects/www.mysite.com/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myprojects/www.mysite.com/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=(search)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/?$ index.php?page=search [QSA,L,NC]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: there is a small correction to your answer. It should be
    RewriteRule ^search/?$ index.php?page=search [QSA,NC,L]

Comment: That is your choice and I won't ask you to change that but your accepted answer is unnecessary long and it doesn't work. If you enter your URL as `/index.php?page=search` that answer won't change it `/search` (first 302 rule isn't working there)

Comment: Just for future reference I have shown you correct way of redirecting `/index.php?page=search` URI.

Comment: I am using wamp server and found no error for my accepted answer.

Comment: What happens when you enter a URL like `/index.php?page=search` ?

Comment: And that is the problem since non pretty URL remains in the browser. This is really bad for SEO since duplicate URLs exist for same page

Comment: Now try my rules and visit this URL again to understand the difference.

Comment: Using your rules, I also found no error for the URL  /index.php?page=search

Comment: You're probably not getting it. Using my rules `/index.php?page=search` will redirect to `/search/` in your browser. Which is the pretty URL you want.

Comment: But my browser (firefox) is not redirecting. That's the problem. I tested on localhost.

Comment: What URL do you see in Firefox location bar and what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: I see the URL as I typed `/index.php?page=search`.  .htaccess is working. There is no doubt because when I type `/search` I find the get variable $_GET['page'] with value search.

Comment: URL starts with `http://` so provide full URL and answer my question correctly on location of .htaccess (relative to DocumentRoot). IN my testing `www.localhost/index.php?page=search` becomes `www.localhost/search/` with above rule.

Comment: location of the .htaccess file is: `http://localhost/myprojects/www.mysite.com/.htaccess`. Note: `www.mysite.com` is the name of a folder. Using your rule , `http://localhost/myprojects/www.mysite.com/index.php?page=search` does't become `http://localhost/myprojects/www.mysite.com/search`.

Comment: See now you are revealing most critical information. i.e you have `/myprojects/www.mysite.com/` before `index.php` which you haven't stated anywhere. Let me update the answer with this.

Comment: Thank a lot again. Now it works. I got my answer. But your current answer isn't relevant enough to the question.  I have accepted your answer. Please make it more relevant to the question I asked. Can you tell me how can I learn .htaccess. I have searched in goole and read many tutorials, but I didn't understand anything.

Comment: Not sure how this answer is not relevant to your question. Anyway refer http://askapache.com for a good reference

Comment: I want to say: I haven't stated the URL `/myprojects/www.mysite.com/` in my question, but in your answer the URL exists. Nothing else. If you think this is OK, then no problem.

Comment: If you want you can edit your question and include this extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the / in ^search?([^/]*)$. So your code should be:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^search?([^\/]*)$ index.php?page=search&$1 [L,NC]
```

I use regexp testers, sometimes they help :)
Heres a link http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to `redirect`?

From

`www.example.com/index.php?page=search&q=string1&type=string2`

To

`www.example.com/search?q=string1&type=string2`

This will works for this case

```
RewriteEngine on

# Stop any redirect loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if it does not starts with /search
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search

# if the query string start with
# page=search, then get the rest
# of the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=search&(.*)

# redirect from:
# ?page=search&q=string1&type=string2
#
# to
# search?q=string1&type=string2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search?%1 [R=302,L] # change to 301

# if the uri starts with search then
# process the url and query string previously redirected
# the flag: QSA 
# appends the query string
RewriteRule ^search/?$ index.php?page=search [QSA,NC,L]
```

And change `R=302` to `R=301`

**Edited to match the new requeriments**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /your/folder/here

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=search[&(.*)]?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search?%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^search/?$ index.php?page=search [QSA,NC,L]
```